# Set an installable edit trigger to fire for a selected cell or range only

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

What I mean is something like this except this one works for simple triggers:

```
function onEdit(e)
{ 
  var range = e.range;
  var columnOfCellEdited = range.getColumn();
  var rowOfCellEdited = range.getRow();

  if ( columnOfCellEdited === 2 && rowOfCellEdited === 1 )
  {
    doSomething();
  }
};
```

What I could think of is

> saving the recent value of the given cell into another cell by every occasion the sheet
>   is edited and check if the value has changed since the last call.

However this solution is pretty far from classy.

**Also do you know any more appropriate ways to restrict the range of the function which is called by an installable trigger?**

Comment: The triggered function must have code guards if you want the trigger function to only execute in certain circumstances. Alternately, consider installing a trigger for a generic handler and calling a specific function if the edited range matches the range you indicate is appropriate for that specific function.

Comment: Typically, there are many more situations for which you don't wont your code to run.  So, if you structure your test as `if (test is NOT true) {return;}//quit if the condition is not met`  This eliminates the need for nesting code in a block.  `if (range.getCell(1, 1).getA1Notation() !== "B1") {return;};`  Also, the event object for the Sheets edit event has a `oldValue` property.